# JavaScript Window Location new tab only when user wants

Tags: javascript

I have some code JavaScript (jQuery) code running to listen to `<a href="">` clicks and replace it with a link from a data attribute.

```
<a class="js-external" href="http://www.google.com/" data-href="/tracking.php?url=http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.js-external').click(function(e) {
      var hrefNew = $(this).attr('data-href');

      if (hrefNew) {
          e.preventDefault();
          window.location.href = hrefNew;
      }

    });
</script>
```

This works as intended but breaks some browser behaviour. If the user `ctrl`+`click`'s on the link (to open it in a new window) the url still gets opened in the same window.

How can I not break the regular browser? Should I also detect if the user is holding down `ctrl` and then use `window.open()`?

Comment: `if(e.ctrlKey) window.open(...)` ?

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But I would also have to add `metaKey` for mac and probably some more edge cases. Is there not a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you are preventing the default action with 
 `e.preventDefault();`

so as you mentioned in your question you have to track pressing the control key and open in new window.

```
  if(e.ctrlKey) 
    window.open(hrefNew)
  else 
    window.location.href = hrefNew;
```

But if you not wish to do so then the easiest way is to set `href` attribute of the anchor dynamically.

```
$('a.js-external').click(function(e) {
    var hrefNew = $(this).attr('data-href');
    if (hrefNew) {
       $(this).attr("href",hrefNew);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/go44o3o3/

Comment: Thanks! Replacing the actual href value seems to work the best. Detecting `ctrlKey` is not enough because there is also middle mouse click, `metaKey` etc. I think the only click it doesn't detect is right mouse -> open in new tab.